# Retrospectively added some tags but git log A..B shows no commits

Tags: git, version-control, git-tag

My repo had the following tags:

```
2.2.1
2.0
1.4
1.3
1.2
```

I retrospectively added 0.0 and 1.0 tags using the following commands:

```
git checkout <SHA of some old commit>
git tag 1.0
git push origin tag 1.0
```

Now when I do the following on `master`

```
git log 1.2..1.0
```

there is no output.

Also, previously following was showing the correct output but now even that is empty

```
git log 2.2.1..2.0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following common sense and lower version tags are placed *before* higher ones, you are asking to run log from a newer revision to an older one.... you should not expect to see much output there. Just like if you ran `git log HEAD..HEAD~2`... there will be nothing coming out of that.

Comment: yeah you're right, I totally didn't notice that! :/